# How to stop *ngFor div content from overlapping in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, css-position, ngfor

I am using ngFor to display reviews one after the other.
I want those divs to be over another image.
It must look something like :
[image]

However I am getting like this below the image :
[image]

I need these reviews to be on top of the above image like in the first pic.

The code I have written is as follows :

```
<div class="position-absolute featured-stories">
        <img src="../../assets/component_3_images/image2.png">
        <h2 class="position-absolute stories-title">Featured <br> Stories</h2>
        <div  *ngFor= "let r of reviews" class="review position-relative">
            <img class = "position-absolute" src="{{ r.src }}"> <p class="ml-5">{{ r.review }} <br> {{ r.date }}</p> 
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have used multiple combinations of position-relative and position-absolute but it ain't working as expected.

How can I bring it to the top without the reviews overlapping each other ?

Comment: You need to add `background-img:<path to your image>` in css to `<div class="position-absolute featured-stories">` rather than image tag.

Comment: will you be able to simulate in stackblitz ? will provide a solution

Answer (score 1):

Use **background**
link beolow

```
<div class="position-absolute featured-stories" style="background:url('../../assets/component_3_images/image2.png'); background-size: cover; background-position: center;">
        
        <h2 class="position-absolute stories-title">Featured <br> Stories</h2>
        <div  *ngFor= "let r of reviews" class="review position-relative">
            <img class = "position-absolute" src="{{ r.src }}"> <p class="ml-5">{{ r.review }} <br> {{ r.date }}</p> 
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
```